# How to test django apps when my authorization is remote?

Tags: python, django, pytest

Currently I am using some tests like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=["default"])
def test_list_boards(api_client):
    baker.make(Board)
    baker.make(Board, name="new")
    url = reverse("v1:boards-list")
    response = api_client().get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(json.loads(response.content)) == 2
```

edit:
since I'm not using django User, this is my custom User:

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, token, name, user_id, email, is_mega_user, is_authenticated):
        self.token = token
        self.name = name
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.email = email
        self.is_mega_user = is_mega_user
        self.is_authenticated = is_authenticated
```

But now, I've added new custom authorization and permission classes in my application, so currently my tests are failling because of it.
And I was thiking: What about when I dont have internet connection? I will not be able to test? How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to test the authorization and permission classes, then switch them out for similarly-behaving, but offline, mocks.

Assuming you're using DRF (guessing because of the terminology of "authorization and permission class" and the use of `api_client`) (though settings changing applies to all frameworks of course), you can

(1) do this in your conftest.py's `pytest_configure`:

```
def pytest_configure():
    from django.conf import settings
    settings.REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES"] = (...)
```

(2) or using [the pytest-django `settings` fixture](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#settings):

```
def test_without_internets(settings):
    settings.REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES"] = (...)
```

which you can naturally package into your own fixture (that could be `autouse` for convenience)

(3) or just plain old `with override_settings()`.

Comment: So, can I set DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES to None?

Comment: Not None, but something custom that works for your tests without needing to contact a remote server.

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not work. Even when change de default authentication class I receive 403 forbbiden.

Comment: But I think it is related to Permission to be honest. To solve it I start every test with `BoardViewSet.permission_classes = [MockedPermission]` (MockedPermission always return True.). But it doesn't seem to be the best practice.

Comment: Well, what's your default permission class like, then?

Comment: I'll upgrade the question and show what I'm doing.